# How to set textColor to an edittext from a CustomAdapter

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an Activity which has an EditText. Within the Activity I also have a ListView which has a search function by calling a CustomAdapter. What I am looking to do is access the EditText from the Custom Adapter so if the search returns nothing, I want to change the text color to RED.

My Adapter class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SetRowsCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SetRows> {
    Context context;
   int layoutResourceId;
   ArrayList<SetRows> data=new ArrayList<SetRows>(); //data = countryList
   private ArrayList<SetRows> originalList;
   private NameFilter filter;
   ImageHolder holder;

   public SetRowsCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<SetRows> data) {
       super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
       this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
       this.context = context;

       this.data = data;
       //this.data.addAll(data);

       this.originalList = new ArrayList<SetRows>();
       this.originalList.addAll(data);
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View row = convertView;
       holder = null;

       if(row == null)
       {
           LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
           row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

           holder = new ImageHolder();
           holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
           holder.txtID = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtModDate);
           holder.txtBen = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtBenefit);
           holder.txtNum = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtNameNum);
           holder.etS = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
           row.setTag(holder);
       }
       else
       {
           holder = (ImageHolder)row.getTag();
       }

       SetRows myImage = data.get(position);
       holder.txtTitle.setText(myImage.name);
       holder.txtID.setText(myImage.id);
       holder.txtNum.setText(myImage.num);
       holder.txtBen.setText(myImage.ben);
       holder.txtBen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      return row;

   }

   static class ImageHolder
   {
       TextView txtTitle;
       TextView txtID;
       TextView txtBen;
       TextView txtNum;
       EditText etS;
   }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null){
            filter  = new NameFilter();
        }
    return filter;
    }
    private class NameFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.US);
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<SetRows> filteredItems = new ArrayList<SetRows>();
                for(int i = 0, l = originalList.size(); i < l; i++) {
                    SetRows nameList = originalList.get(i);
                    if(nameList.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains(constraint))
                        filteredItems.add(nameList);
                }
                result.count = filteredItems.size();
                result.values = filteredItems;
            }
            else {
                synchronized(this) {
                    result.values = originalList;
                    result.count = originalList.size();
                }
            }
        return result;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            data = (ArrayList<SetRows>)results.values;
            if (data.isEmpty()) {
                holder.etS.setText("ll");
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No result found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // returns blank
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            for(int i = 0, l = data.size(); i < l; i++)
                add(data.get(i));
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
```

`holder.etS.setText("ll");` is throwing an exception with the following LogCat:

```
01-09 19:34:25.566: E/AndroidRuntime(13668): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 19:34:25.566: E/AndroidRuntime(13668): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 19:34:25.566: E/AndroidRuntime(13668):    at com.test.testing.SetRowsCustomAdapter$NameFilter.publishResults(SetRowsCustomAdapter.java:119)
01-09 19:34:25.566: E/AndroidRuntime(13668):    at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
01-09 19:34:25.566: E/AndroidRuntime(13668):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 19:34:25.566: E/AndroidRuntime(13668):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 19:34:25.566: E/AndroidRuntime(13668):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
01-09 19:34:25.566: E/AndroidRuntime(13668):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 19:34:25.566: E/AndroidRuntime(13668):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-09 19:34:25.566: E/AndroidRuntime(13668):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-09 19:34:25.566: E/AndroidRuntime(13668):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
01-09 19:34:25.566: E/AndroidRuntime(13668):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was simply use `Activity` casting on `context` and it worked fine :)

```
EditText I = (EditText) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
I.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCCCC"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you have only on holder and the reference had lost.

You should save holder for each row of your list view.
So, Do the next:

- Define 
  Map '<'Integer,ImageHolder>
  it is dictionary that will save your holders for each row.
- Inside getView(..) method, after you save data in the holder, put it in the already created Map.
- Now, in publishResults(..) method, make foreach loop for all holders and change the color on the text in editText.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor pass the edit text reference and hold on to it. then use that reference to update color. Why u need holder for a view outside of the list view item?

Comment: I am using an edit text which uses a search filter to allow user to search which is outside of the list view. How do I pass reference of edit text?

Comment: Through the constructor, and a variable of type EditText to your adapter to hold on to it

Comment: How do I set pass the variable of type EditText?